# How to implement PayUMoney payment gateway in angular 8

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I tried to implement payment gateway in my angular 8 project but not working.I followed this :https://www.devglan.com/angular/payumoney-integration-angular
If anyone know please help to find the solution.

Demo :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-wz3ot1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fbilling.dir.ts

Comment: hi @Nila Vaani did you find the solution?

Comment: No..till now did not find the solution

Comment: where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

**There is a very simple way to integrate it.**

```
const paymentDetails = {
    payu_url: '', // add payu url
    first_name: '', // user name
    email: '', // user email
    mobile: '', // user mobile
    callback_url: '', // callback url
    payu_cancel_url: '', // callback cancel url
    payu_fail_url: '', // callback fail url
    payu_merchant_key: '', // payu merchant key
    payu_sha_token: '', // payu hash token
    txnid: '', // unique txnid
    plan_name: '', // name
    amount: '', // amount
    service_provider: '' // service 
};

let paymentString = `
    <html>
      <body>
        <form action="${paymentDetails.payu_url}" method="post" id="payu_form">
          <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="${paymentDetails.first_name}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${paymentDetails.email}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="${paymentDetails.mobile}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="${paymentDetails.callback_url}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="curl" value="${paymentDetails.payu_cancel_url}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="${paymentDetails.payu_fail_url}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${paymentDetails.payu_merchant_key}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="${paymentDetails.payu_sha_token}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="${paymentDetails.txnid}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="${paymentDetails.plan_name}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="${paymentDetails.amount}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="${paymentDetails.service_provider}"/>
          <button type="submit" value="submit" #submitBtn></button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("payu_form").submit();</script>
      </body>
    </html>`;

const winUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([paymentString], { type: "text/html" })
);

window.location.href = winUrl;
```

you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS7hOur9X-M) video, here it describe in simple way